# Is it possible to setup in Visual Studio or other IDEs?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, ide, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to install flutter on VS 2019 IDE (not Visual Studio Code or Android Studio/IntelliJ)?

I can't find anything for VS 2019, but only for VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Flutter FAQ](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#does-flutter-work-with-any-editors-or-ides):

> ### Does Flutter work with any editors or IDEs?
>
> We support plugins for [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio), [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).
>
> See [editor configuration](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor) for setup details, and [Android Studio/IntelliJ](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio) and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for tips on how to use the plugins.
>
> Alternatively, you can use a combination of the `flutter` command in a terminal and one of the many editors that support [editing Dart](https://dart.dev/tools).

#### So, no

You cannot get the same tooling in Visual Studio that you can get in *Android Studio/IntelliJ and VS Code* because the Flutter team does not work on support for any other IDEs.
If you visit [IDEs and editors for Dart](https://dart.dev/tools#ides-and-editors), you can see what code editors have support for editing Dart code and you can use that in conjunction with the `flutter` command to get a similar experience.